# Easy-to-use django captcha or registration app with captcha?

Tags: django, captcha, registration

I want to implement user registration using captcha in Django.
The workflow of [django-registration](http://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/wiki/Home) app is a great, but it doesn't have captcha.

What captcha would you recommend to use with it?
Are there some other variants of registration+captcha or useful links on the topic?

This should work with Django-1.1 and don't be too hard to install.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

django-registration is pretty extendable. One way to extend it is to provide a custom registration form. I'd recommend to use [reCaptcha](http://recaptcha.net/), e.g. with the widget and form field from [here](http://lobstertech.com/2008/aug/27/integrating_django_recaptcha/) ([archived](http://web.archive.org/web/20090606022756/http://lobstertech.com/2008/aug/27/integrating_django_recaptcha/)). Then it is as simple as writing a custom form class and registration backend (which is simpler than it sounds):

```
from registration.backends.default import DefaultBackend
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm

class RecaptchaRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm)
    recaptcha = ReCaptchaField(label="I'm a human")

class RecaptchaRegistrationBackend(DefaultBackend):
    def get_form_class(self, request):
        return RecaptchaRegistrationForm
```

The last step is to tell django-registration to use your backend. That step is described in the [docs](http://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/tip/docs/backend-api.rst#cl-44) (I couldn't find a HTML version of the docs, sorry)

Comment: the link to the widget and form field gives a 502

Comment: Fortunately, archive.org has a copy: http://web.archive.org/web/20090606022756/http://lobstertech.com/2008/aug/27/integrating_django_recaptcha/

Comment: You can avoid subclassing registration backend setting the form class in your `urls.py` as backend argument. For example: `(r'^register/$', RegistrationView.as_view(form_class=RegistrationForm))`.

Answer (score 21):

I've just had this problem, but the solution is dead simple.

I'm using [django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration), and I want a reCAPTCHA field for user registration. In just 1 minute:

1. download [django-recaptcha](https://github.com/praekelt/django-recaptcha) (`pip install django-recaptcha`)
2. install it on your project. That is, copy the "captcha" folder to your project, add "captcha" to `INSTALLED_APPS` and add your `RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY` and `RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY` keys to settings.py too (as described in the installation instructions)
3. open `registration/forms.py` and add this field inside `class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):`

   `captcha = ReCaptchaField()`

   you will also have to import:

   `from captcha.fields import ReCaptchaField`

And that's it. Less than a minute.

Comment: No kidding - followed your instructions and it took less than a minute.. Thanks!

Comment: But what if the registration package is not copied into your project and instead installed via pip install ... ?

Answer (score 16):

For those like me arriving late to the thread, there are a bunch of solutions out there now, which are pretty easy to install:

- http://code.google.com/p/django-simple-captcha/
- http://code.google.com/p/django-captcha/
- https://github.com/inueni/django-captcha-field
- https://github.com/justquick/django-math-captcha
- https://github.com/marconi/django-mollom which uses the third-party Mollom service (which provides captcha and spam-filtering services).

I've successfully setup Django Mollom and Django Simple Captcha, and the hardest part was yak shaving around installing PIL on my Mac. Implementing the code was as straightforward as the docs for each would suggest.