# Django-registration and ReCaptcha integration - how to pass the user's IP

Tags: python, django, registration, recaptcha

New to django and trying to setup django-registration 0.8 with recaptcha-client. I followed the advice posted in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275806/easy-to-use-django-captcha-or-registration-app-with-captcha).

I used the custom form and custom backend from that post and the widget and field from [this tutorial](http://lobstertech.com/2008/aug/27/integrating_django_recaptcha/). My form is displaying properly with the recaptcha widget but when I submit it throws the error about the missing IP. What's the best way to pass the IP using django-registration?

Comment: Recaptcha is terrible.  I'm not your free OCR slave.

Comment: Opened this question in expectation of many thread-local based solutions that leak the request from the view. Yet there are no answers so far. I hope you don't end up doing something like that.

Answer (score 2):

I also used the code from the tutorial you linked, in my case to add reCaptcha to the django comments app.

You need something like `initial={'captcha': request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']}` at the point where your RecaptchaRegistrationForm gets instantiated.

Unfortunately this is buried in the registration/views.py register method.

You need to do something like copy and paste their code into a view method of your own and edit it. Then you need a urls.py for your customised backend that looks like the one in registration/backends/default/ but points to your new register view in place of theirs.